# Add rows to pandas dataframe based on cyclic column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has some missing rows, which I can tell by evaluating the `cycle` column. This column cycles through 0-127 and repeats, till the end of the dataframe. I can tell that a row is missing if, for example, the values on this column jump from 36 to 38, meaning that the row corresponding to `cycle = 37` is missing.

Here's an example of that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Acc12019-08-08T21_52_46.3175552+01_00.csv')

      Command  RegisterAddress  Timestamp  accx  ...  magx  magy  magz  cycle
27          3               34   115.0948   -83  ...  79.0  80.0 -78.0   35.0
28          3               34   115.1004   -34  ...  79.0  80.0 -78.0   36.0
29          3               34   115.1048    36  ...  79.0  80.0 -80.0   38.0
      ...              ...        ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
3731        3               34   140.0191  1238  ...  44.0 -90.0 -39.0   30.0
3732        3               34   140.0235  1243  ...  44.0 -90.0 -38.0   31.0
3733        3               34   140.0293  1368  ...  43.0 -90.0 -35.0   33.0
```

What I want to do is add rows of `NaN`s where this condition is not met. Below is the expected outcome:

```
27          3               34   115.0948   -83  ...  79.0  80.0 -78.0   35.0
28          3               34   115.1004   -34  ...  79.0  80.0 -78.0   36.0
          NaN              NaN        NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN   37.0
29          3               34   115.1048    36  ...  79.0  80.0 -80.0   38.0
```

The missing rows are random and can happen at any `cycle` position, so I believe that the first thing would be to check where the `cycle` missing rows are. Note that, in the example above, `cycle=32` is also missing in the subsequent cycle.

I've tried to look for ways of finding missing numbers on a list [like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-missing-numbers-in-a-sorted-list-range/), but so far with no success implementing it on my dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `set` to find missing rows;
`append`, `sort_values`, and `reset_index` to add them to the original dataframe.

```py
# assume `lst` is a list containing all possible `cycle` values
lst = [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
missing = pd.DataFrame({'cycle': list(set(df['cycle']) ^ set(lst))})
```

```py
# missing.head()
    cycle
0   37
1   39
2   40
```

```py
df.append(missing).sort_values(['cycle']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

[image]

---

Posted an image, because `to_clipboard()` output is all messed up.

Comment: Now that I have re-read your question, I don't this would work nicely given repeating cycles. Maybe someone could address this issue specifically

Comment: Yes, the repeated cycles make it a little bit harder :/ but i still really apprecited your response. If you come up with an idea on how to deal with it, please let me know. I'm fairly new to programming so any help is welcome. Cheers!